# optimized dex types in dalvik cache

Tags: android, bytecode, dalvik, vm-implementation

In /data/dalvik-cache we found two formats (system and data),

```
data@app@com.foo.apk@classes.dex
```

and

```
system@app@com.foo.apk@classes.dex
```

What do they mean? I mean what is meant by `data` and `system` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That refers to the path of the apk on the device. In your two examples, the paths would be /data/app/com.foo.apk and /system/app/com.foo.apk. In other words, the system@app odex files are for system applications installed on the system partition, and the data@app odex files are for applications that have been installed and live on the data partition.

Comment: hi the dex files there are they the optimized dex or odex? because when I do dexdump -d for the original classes.dex and the classes.dex there they are exactly same.

Comment: Yes, they are odex files